# Partial Trace of Werner State

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra

I am trying to trace out the second qubit of the Werner State:
\begin{align}
W &=\frac{1-s}{4}I_{4}+\frac{s}{2}(|00\rangle\langle{00}|+|11\rangle\langle11|+|11\rangle \langle00|+|00\rangle \langle 11|)\\[0.5em]&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 (1+s)/4 & 0 & 0 & s/2 \\
 0 & (1-s)/4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & (1-s)/4 & 0 \\
 s/2 & 0 & 0 & (1+s)/4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

I write down $I_{4}=|11\rangle \langle11|+|00\rangle \langle00|+|10\rangle \langle10|+|01\rangle \langle01|$ and the result is:
\begin{align}
W&=\frac{1+s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|\otimes|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1+s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|\otimes|1\rangle \langle1|\\ &+\frac{1-s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|\otimes|1\rangle \langle1|+\frac{1-s}{4}|1\rangle \langle 1|\otimes|0\rangle \langle0| \\
&+\frac{s}{2}|0\rangle \langle1|\otimes|0\rangle \langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|1\rangle \langle0|\otimes|1\rangle \langle0|
\end{align}

Thus tracing out the second qubit results to:
\begin{align}
W_{A}&=\frac{1+s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1+s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|+\frac{1-s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1-s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|0\rangle \langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|1\rangle \langle0|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|0\rangle \langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|1\rangle \langle 0|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & s \\
 s & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}.

However the result in the notes seems to be:

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1/2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1/2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}.

I am stuck and I try to find my mistake but i can't. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{s}{2}|0\rangle\langle1|\otimes|0\rangle\langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|1\rangle\langle0|\otimes|1\rangle\langle0|$ should disappear when you take the trace over them, as $\langle0|1\rangle$ and $\langle1|0\rangle = 0$

Edit: To give a simpler example, if your traced out the second qubit of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle+|11\rangle$$, then $\frac{1}{2}|00\rangle\langle11|$ and $\frac{1}{2}|11\rangle\langle00|$ would also disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$
\mathrm{tr}_B\left(|0\rangle \langle1|\otimes|0\rangle \langle1|\right) =|0\rangle \langle1| \mathrm{tr} (|0\rangle \langle1|) = |0\rangle \langle1| \, \langle1|0\rangle = |0\rangle \langle1| \cdot 0 = 0
$$

so the two terms marked red below disappear when you take the partial trace

$$
W_{A}=\frac{1+s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1+s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|+\frac{1-s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1-s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|+\color{red}{\frac{s}{2}|0\rangle \langle1|+\frac{s}{2}|1\rangle \langle0|}.
$$

Once these terms are gone, the rest of the calculations yields

$$
\begin{align}
W_{A}&=\frac{1+s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1+s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|+\frac{1-s}{4}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1-s}{4}|1\rangle \langle1|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \langle0|+\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \langle1|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
$$

as expected.

---

There is another way of computing the partial trace from the full density matrix that works particularly well in this case

$$
W_A = \mathrm{tr}_B\begin{pmatrix}
 (1+s)/4 & 0 & 0 & s/2 \\
 0 & (1-s)/4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & (1-s)/4 & 0 \\
 s/2 & 0 & 0 & (1+s)/4 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
 \mathrm{tr}\begin{pmatrix}
(1+s)/4 & 0 \\
0 & (1-s)/4
\end{pmatrix} & \mathrm{tr}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & s/2 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
\mathrm{tr}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
s/2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} & \mathrm{tr}\begin{pmatrix}
(1-s)/4 & 0 \\
 0 & (1+s)/4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Oh my god I feel so dumb and tired. Thanks man!!